# Failing to Docker Virtual Box as per Part 4 of Docker Getting Started

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, docker-for-windows

I am playing with Docker Swarms as defined in part 4 of getting started.  Reference [Part 4](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part4/)

When running the `docker-machine create --driver virtualbox myvm1` command to create a virtual machine, the following error is shown:

> docker-machine : Error with pre-create check: "This computer is running Hyper-V. VirtualBox won't boot a 64bits VM when Hyper-V is activated. Either use Hyper-V as a 
>   driver, or disable the Hyper-V hypervisor. (To skip this check, use --virtualbox-no-vtx-check)"

I have installed the latest versions of Docker and Virtual Box.  Plus Hyper-V is set on my PC.  For reference, the operating systems is Windows 10.

Does anyone have any ideas or solutions to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Disable Hyper-V.

The program is telling you that you can either disable the check by running it with the `--virtualbox-no-vtx-check` flag (like this: `docker-machine create --driver virtualbox myvm1 --virtualbox-no-vtx-check` **Not recommended**) or by disabling Hyper-V.

This is because Hyper-V seems to lock Intel VT-X (The virtualization accelerator which Virtualbox needs)

You can do this from the Windows Features menu (just type `Features` in the Windows Search bar.)

Source: Personal experience and the error message.